# Javascript regular expression,how to allows empty string for page value for printing

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a regular expression that check for the Page value entered for printing the pages, like 1-7 or 1-3,7 or 1-3,5-7. regex is working for all the cases, I want to allow blank as a page value, so that it should not validate blank and print all pages. i'm allowing user to type some special characters like [&,-;_]. How to allow blank or empty string for this regex. Page value should start with a digit and end with a digit.

```
var pageValue = document.getElementById("pages" + counter);
var regex = /^\d([&,-;_]\d+)*$/
//if page value is wrong, return null and display error message here
 if(regex.test(pageValue.value) == false) {
alert("Invalid page number: " + pageValue.value);
    return;
  }
```

i'm testing with all these page values.
match found: 2-3
match found: 1,2
match found: 3-1
not a match          --- want to match empty string
match found: 1_2
not a match ABC
match found: 1&2
match found: 1;2
not a match -1-9
not a match 1-9-
match found: 1-5,13
match found: 1-5;13
match found: 1-5,13-23
not a match 1-5,13-23;

Comment: match found: 2-3
match found: 1,2
match found: 3-1
not a match:        <-- want to match empty string 
match found: 1_2
not a match ABC
match found: 1&2
match found: 1;2
not a match -1-9
not a match 1-9-
match found: 1-5,13
match found: 1-5;13
match found: 1-5,13-23
not a match 1-5,13-23;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var regex = /^(\d([&,;_-]\d+)*)?$/
```

to allow blank as accepted value.

**PS:** It is important to keep `-` (hyphen) as first or last in character class to avoid escaping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply anubhava: i tried with your answer, its failing if the page value is -1-9, so i don't want the user to allow enter -1 as page value

Comment: ok then please make it clear in your question what patterns you don't want.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, it's working, i was testing all cases again so took me a while.